# Парсинг iframe через selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

Как получить данные iframe вида:

```
<iframe src="https://site?emb-token=fdsfadsfdasfadsfadsf" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto" class="iframe-proxy">
```

Данный код является частью html страницы.
при попытки переключения через

```
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
```

выдается как я думаю вложенный в главный фрейм код, но других индексов фреймов на странице нет.

По сути мне в этом фрейме нужно скачать файл, но без прямого клика на ссылку файл не скачивается. Думаю из-за того что должен подставляться токен фрейма.

Answer (score 1):

Решил с помощью последовательного поиска по fullXPATH.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[4]/iframe'))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/div[1]/div/ul/div/li[1]/div/section/div/a/span').click()
```